# How many addresses does bitcoind use for Bitcoin generation?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, mining-pools, protocol, mining-reward

When bitcoind is generating Bitcoins, does it change the addresses that are used for receiving the block reward? That is, if I mine two blocks with the same bitcoind wallet.dat, will the same address be credited with both of the rewards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you generate a new block with "getwork" then bitcoind will always use a new address each time.

If you generate a new block with "getmemorypool", then you decide. You can do whatever you want because you are creating the block data yourself. "getmemorypool" is new with bitcoind 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

Each block reward will be credited to a different address. No more than one address per block is used in the generation process.

Comment: Hmm, is there any way to suppress this behaviour and use one and the same address every time?

Comment: You'd need to change the code, though I think it'd be a pretty easy change to make.